# sails.js: making requests etag (If-None-Match) has no effect

Tags: sails.js, etag

I'm playing around with sails' (express) etag support. However, I fail completely doing something other people apparently had no problems with.

Using sails.js version 0.11.0

etags are by default enabled in sails.js. I can also see them in the response header.

When trying to make a request with this header, e.g.:

```
If-None-Match: "21d-3538299541"
```

I just receive the standard 200-response. I don't do anything special. Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong?